# javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [jersey]: could not be initialized Websphere Liberty

Tags: java, jersey, websphere-liberty

I am trying to run my web application on Websphere Liberty and I get the following error:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [jersey]: could not be initialized
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4913)
        at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [jersey]: could not be initialized
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:163)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.ScannerException: The URI scheme wsjar of the URI wsjar:file:/opt/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/expanded/eureka.war/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-servlet-1.11.jar!/com/sun/jersey is not supported. Package scanning deployment is not supported for such URIs.
Try using a different deployment mechanism such as explicitly declaring root resource and provider classes using an extension of javax.ws.rs.core.Application
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:225)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:139)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:719)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:149)
        ... 1 more
```

I am using Websphere Liberty 8.5.5.9.